# Is there way to describe function for transforming object?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that doing something like this

```js
function transform(obj) {
  const returnedObj = { custom: {} };

  for (key in obj.wrap.custom) {
    returnedObj.custom[key] = obj.wrap.custom[key];
  }

  return returnedObj;
}
```

What is the right way to describe types?
I have tried in this way

```js
interface ITransformingObject {
  wrap: {
    custom: {[key: string]: string}
  }
}

interface IReturnedObject {
  custom: ITransformingObject['wrap']['custom']
}

function transform(obj: ITransformingObject): IReturnedObject {
  const returnedObj = { custom: {} };

  for (const key in obj.wrap.custom) {
    returnedObj.custom[key] = obj.wrap.custom[key];
  }

  return returnedObj;
}

const a = { 
  wrap: { 
    custom: {
      test: 'test'
    }
  }
}
const b = transform(a);
```

But I'm not sure that it's correct. For example, IntelliSense doesn't see the properties of `a.custom`. Can I better describe the return type to define that keys of `a.custom` must be the same as keys of `a.wrap.custom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep track of the specific object types inside the `custom` properties, you need to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), like this:

```
interface ITransformingObject<T extends object> {
  wrap: {
    custom: T
  }
}

interface IReturnedObject<T extends object> {
  custom: T
}

function transform<T extends object>(obj: ITransformingObject<T>): IReturnedObject<T> {
  const returnedObj = { custom: {} } as IReturnedObject<T>;

  for (const key in obj.wrap.custom) {
    returnedObj.custom[key] = obj.wrap.custom[key];
  }

  return returnedObj;
}
```

Here an `ITransformingObject<T>` has a `wrap` property with a `custom` property of type `T`, for some objectlike `T` you specify.  And `IReturnedObject<T>` is the same but without the `wrap` wrapper.  Then `transform()` is also generic; its parameter is of type `ITransformingObject<T>` for some `T`, and then returns a value of type `IReturnedObject<T>` for the *same* `T`.

Also note that for this to compile with no error I needed to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `returnedObject` is of type `IReturnedObject<T>`, because it isn't initially true (certainly at initialization, the value `{}` is unlikely to be of type `T`).

Now, when you call `transform()`, the compiler will *infer* the type argument `T` for you based on the type of the value you pass in:

```
const a = {
  wrap: {
    custom: {
      test: 'test'
    }
  }
}

const b = transform(a);
/* function transform<{
    test: string;
}>(obj: ITransformingObject<{
    test: string;
}>): IReturnedObject<{
    test: string;
}> */
```

See how `T` is inferred as `{test: string}`, and so `b` is of type `IReturnedObject<{test: string}>`.  Meaning the compiler now knows about what properties are expected to be present or not expected to be present in `b.custom`:

```
console.log(b.custom.test.toUpperCase()); // compiles fine, "TEST"
b.custom.nope // compiler error, nope does not exist on {test: string}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBUpxAZxgeygFtQBzAeQCMArCBMAHnWQgA9IQATHZfGusAD5kAbwBQyZAHcsABwBcoiZOQIArjjD4ii9MoC+Yw2NCRYiFKgBKEMGqggInKrXpMW7CFx59XQpZLqmtq6RmJiMGog9MD4IMhgWLgExO5sHNy8-PSCABS+ihhJeIQkIBTZjOiCAJSFNnYOTi4CTMLigXGayFC29o7ONMgAvKKqGlo6ovrIM3A81n1Ng35tANzhkinIuQhdYMgA1hAAnsigWdQAdDJwsldBkzUBKr2NAy4PE9oA2scnAF0RpcbnIvsEiH9TgCNpJjJI3v0eksPjQNsY9rgDnBgR1pHJFHjAt8pkSVJBNIoAOQUsBU5RwgxhTHdSjAxLYErEXJwGobAD0ACpkJFomBYvEOclSgwybTFJooGR0XkCmhMJyUmUKqs5RBKchFcqjLV6ijmpVZQyEvqwArEsb9MJBfzwiz8AAbCBXD34Ui5SjgyZXWkh-AAVVksmgAGF5hBcjU+ch+fzkAAidAAUQAyuh02JA49tFcQPhoym03siLJgF6oCwoFBCAAaZBliucfD69v4A5sYDdOKieWGh3lfRAA)